# Problems with a header menu

Tags: css

I am trying to make a header menu work as I like. I have only minor experience with CSS.

I have only two main menu items, each with a dropdown. I want for it to look something like this when hover on first menu item:
[image]

And something like this when hovering on second menu item:
[image]

Note: I want the "Menu 1" and "Menu 2" to be positioned as they are in the images, including this: Dropdown for Menu 1 is to the right of Menu 1, dropdown of Menu 2 is to the left of Menu 2. I forgot to include "Logo" in the images, but it is centered in the middle.

I have a fiddle of what I have managed so far ([check it out here](https://jsfiddle.net/frodefi/hq2o800q/)).

I have two problems:

- The width is not 100%. The blue background is 100%, but I tried for the two menu items to be 25% each and then there is a logo-div in the middle that should fill out the rest (with margin: auto), so it is 100% all together.
- The active main menu item gets pushed down on hover

How to fix it to work as intended?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  background-color: royalblue;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 3.15em;
  color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
}

.nav h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.nav:first-of-type h3 {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  top:36px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 15em;
  margin-top: 4em;
  display: none;
}

.nav:nth-of-type(2) ul {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav:hover ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.width-25 {
  width: 25%;
}

.fill-width {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <section class="nav">
    <h3 class="width-25">Menu&nbsp;item&nbsp;1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">Dropdown 1 item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">Dropdown 1/2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">item 1 # 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">Dropdown 1 item 4 long</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">DD 1-5</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">Dropdown 1 i. 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <span class="fill-width">Logo</span>
  <section class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">Dropdown 2 item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">Dropdown 2/2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">item 2 # 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">Dropdown 2 item 4 long</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">DD 2-5</a></li>
      <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">Dropdown 2 i. 6</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="width-25">Menu&nbsp;item&nbsp;2</h3>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your fiddle with a way of how you could do this.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisG87/hq2o800q/7/)

It probably isn't the best or the cleanest way, but I did this in about 10 mins quickly. It should give you a base on how to go further.

The main problem was pretty much not giving your h3 seperate classes like so:

```
<h3 class="right">
```

I hope this helps you with your problem :).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Chris. I was a little bit unclear, I updated the question, but I guess you started to answer before that: I want the "Menu 1" and "Menu 2" to be positioned as they are in the images, including this: Dropdown for Menu 1 is to the right of Menu 1, dropdown of Menu 2 is to the left of Menu 2.

Comment: @EricC: Updated my JSFiddle in my post. Go and check it out!

Comment: Great! Almost there :) One thing: Is it possible to have the dropdowns always be positions as in my images: The dropdown of Menu 1 is always immediately to the right of the text "Menu 1", and the dropdown of Menu 2 is always immediately to the left of the text "Menu 2"? Currently the position (related to the main menu text) changes depending in browser window width...

Comment: @EricC: Updated again with everything you want. I added new divs to surround the menu items with a default width%. I hope you like it :).

Comment: Great :) Thanks a lot for your help, Chris!

Comment: Oh, I just see one huge problem with the solution: It is impossible to move the pointer from hovering the man menu item to the dropdown, the dropdown disappears...

Comment: I'll look into that. Give me a few :)

Comment: @EricC: Updated my JSFiddle again in my post. Go check it out :)

Comment: Just perfect! Thanks again, Chris :)

Answer (score 2):

Some few things:

1. Add `position: relative` to `.nav`.
2. Give `position: absolute` to `.nav ul`.

Now check this out:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.header {
  background-color: royalblue;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 3.15em;
  color: green;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
}
.nav h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}
section {
  display: inline-block;
  body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  background-color: royalblue;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 3.15em;
  color: green;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
}

.nav h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav:first-of-type h3 {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  top:36px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 15em;
  margin-top: 4em;
  display: none;
}

.nav:nth-of-type(2) ul {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav:hover ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.width-25 {
  width: 25%;
}

.fill-width {
  margin: auto;
}

}
.nav:first-of-type h3 {
  text-align: right;
}
.nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  top: 36px;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 15em;
  margin-top: 4em;
  display: none;
}
.nav:nth-of-type(2) ul {
  text-align: right;
}
.nav:hover ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
.width-25 {
  width: 25%;
}
.fill-width {
  margin: auto;
}
.nav {
  position: relative;
}
.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <section class="nav">
    <h3 class="width-25">Toolbox</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/es6" class="menu-link">ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)</a></li>
      <li><a href="/typescript" class="menu-link">TypeScript/ES7</a></li>
      <li><a href="/obserables" class="menu-link">Observables</a></li>
      <li><a href="/build" class="menu-link">Building/Deploying</a></li>
      <li><a href="/components" class="menu-link">Components</a></li>
      <li><a href="/testing" class="menu-link">View/Input Data</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <span class="fill-width"></span>
  <section class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/forms" class="menu-link">Forms</a></li>
      <li><a href="/pipes" class="menu-link">Pipes</a></li>
      <li><a href="/services" class="menu-link">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="/directives" class="menu-link">Directives</a></li>
      <li><a href="/di" class="menu-link">Dependency Injection</a></li>
      <li><a href="/testing" class="menu-link">Testing</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="width-25">Angular&nbsp;2</h3>
  </section>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I was unclear (updated question also): I want the "Menu 1" and "Menu 2" to be positioned as they are in the images, including this: Dropdown for Menu 1 is to the right of Menu 1, dropdown of Menu 2 is to the left of Menu 2. I forgot to include "Logo" in the images, but it is centered in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the position to absolute on the `<ul>` element to fix the issue of active menu getting pushed on hover.

```
position: absolute;
```

Check out this updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05bccccf/).

Also, what do you mean by the width is not 100%?

Comment: Regarding unclear 100% question (updated question): The width is not 100%. The blue background is 100%, but I tried for the two menu items to be 25% each and then there is a logo-div in the middle that should fill out the rest (with margin: auto), so it is 100% all together.

Comment: I was unclear (updated question also): I want the "Menu 1" and "Menu 2" to be positioned as they are in the images, including this: Dropdown for Menu 1 is to the right of Menu 1, dropdown of Menu 2 is to the left of Menu 2. I forgot to include "Logo" in the images, but it is centered in the middle.